# SIGSEGV error occurs in implementation of a hash table in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a hash table data structure in C++, but every time i run the program i get a run time error(SIGSEGV, segmentation fault) in line number 86 like here.

[image: (some thing like this)]

> i.e.: `putInHash(str,hashTable,m); in main().`

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
struct node *next,*prev;
string data;
}node;

int hashCode(string str)
{
char arr[str.size()+1];
strcpy(arr,str.c_str());
int code=0;
   for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
   {
    code+=((i+1)*((int)arr[i]));
   }
return code;
}

int compress(int k,int m)
{
   double a=(sqrt(5.0)-1)/2;
   return floor(m*(fmod(k*a,1)));
}

void display(node* hashTable[],int m)
{
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
       cout<<i<<":\n";
       node* p=hashTable[i];
       while(p!=NULL)
       {
          cout<<p->data<<" , ";
       }
       cout<<"\n";
   }
}

void putInHash(string str,node* hashTable[],int m)
{
   int k=hashCode(str);
   int bucket=compress(k,m);
   if(hashTable[bucket]==NULL)
   {
       hashTable[bucket]=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
       hashTable[bucket]->prev=NULL;
       hashTable[bucket]->next=NULL;
       hashTable[bucket]->data=str;
   }
   else
   {
       node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
       temp->data=str;
       temp->next=hashTable[bucket];
       hashTable[bucket]->prev=temp;
       temp->prev=NULL;
       hashTable[bucket]=temp;
   }
}

int main()
{
   cout<<"Enter number of strings to add in hash table: ";
   long int n;
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"\n";
   int m=13;
   node* hashTable[m];
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
   {
       hashTable[i]=NULL;
   }

   string str;

   cout<<"Enter the strings:\n";
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       cin>>str;
       putInHash(str,hashTable,m);
   }

   display(hashTable,m);

   return 0;
}
```

I thought it might be due to passing the string, but it turned out this wasn't the case.

Can somebody please guide me through it.
I think the error may be in passing the `hashTable[]` as an argument.

Comment: You need to compile your code in debug mode, and than run it inside debugger. Debugger will catch the signal. Than you will be able to look into state of variables to check what went wrong.

Comment: You should be more careful with `malloc`; there's no guarantee it was able to obtain enough memory for your `node*`. That may not be the error you're getting, but it's definitely something you should shore up.

Comment: I bet you didnt even compile it because of `char arr[str.size()+1];`. It would produce error as long as str.size() is not a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem (I'm using clang++ in a Linux platform and I suppose that your problem is platform dependent) but I see something that can explain it.

You use `malloc()` to allocate memory for a struct with a `std::string` in it.

This is bad.

Really, really bad.

Because `malloc()` can allocate the memory but can't construct the `data` member in it.

In C++ you should use `new`; at least, allocating not trivial objects (`std::string` isn't trivial).

```
// node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));  // DANGEROUS
node * temp = new node;
```

This is the problem that cause the sigsegv (I suppose) but your code has a lot of other problem.

Example: the `while` in `display()` goes in loop because `p` remain unchanged; you should change `display()` in this way

```
void display (node * hashTable[], int m)
{
   node * p;

   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
      cout << i << ":\n";

      for ( p = hashTable[i] ; p ; p = p->next )
         cout << p->data << " , ";

      cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Another important point: variable length arrays isn't C++; it's C (C99). So this lines are wrong

```
char arr[str.size()+1];
node* hashTable[m];
```

You don't need the first (absolutely useless) and you can simplify `hashcode()` in this way (and please, pass the strings by const reference, when possible)

```
int hashCode (const string & str)
 {
   int code = 0;

   for ( int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; ++i )
      code += (i+1) * int(str[i]);

   return code;
 }
```

About `hashTable`, you can substitute it with a `std::vector`

```
  // node* hashTable[m];  no C++
  //for(int i=0;i<m;i++)   // useless
  //{                      // useless
  //    hashTable[i]=NULL; // useless
  //}                      // useless

  std::vector<node *>  hashTable(m, NULL);  // m NULL node pointers
```

Obviously, `putInHash()` should be

```
void putInHash (string str, std::vector<node*> & hashTable, int m)
```

and `display()`

```
void display (const std::vector<node*> & hashTable, int m)
```

And remember to free the allocated memory.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

**--- EDIT ---**

phonetagger is right: deleting the memory (a vector o linked nodes) isn't trivial.

I suggest a function like the following

```
void recursiveFreeNode (node * & nd)
 {
   if ( nd )
    {
      recursiveFreeNode(nd->next);

      delete nd; // added with EDIT 2; sorry

      nd = NULL; // useless, in this, case, but good practice
    }
 }
```

and call it (for every node of the vector) in `main()`, after `display()` calling

```
for ( unsigned ui = 0U ; ui < hashTable.size() ; ++ui )
   recursiveFreeNode(hashTable[ui]);
```

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

Sorry: I've forgot the more important line: `delete node` (thanks phonetagger).

Following the other suggestion of phonetagger, I propose a not-recursive function for deleting the hashtable's node

```
void loopFreeNode (node * & nd)
 {
   node *  tmp;

   for ( ; nd ; nd = tmp )
    {
      tmp = nd->next;

      delete nd;
    }

   nd = NULL;
 }
```

Obviously the `for` loop, to use `loopFreeNode()`, should be

```
for ( unsigned ui = 0U ; ui < hashTable.size() ; ++ui )
   loopFreeNode(hashTable[ui]);
```

Comment: Your `recursiveFreeNode()` function isn't actually doing anything, except guaranteeing that the `node` memory is leaked, since your pointers are simple raw pointers. Perhaps you meant to `delete node` before NULLing it? Also, since the last action of the function isn't the call to itself, it's not possible for the compiler to TCO the function. It probably won't matter in practice, but if the hashtable has an inordinate amount of collisions, it could lead to stack overflow. The function could just as easily be implemented as a loop, instead of recursively, which would not eat stack space.

Comment: @phonetagger: d'oh! Yes, you're right: I forgot the most important line: `delete node`. Thanks. And not only: I've given to the variable the same name of the struct. I've tried to write a not recursive function but I don't find really elegant. Feel free to modify it or to add a better version.